# Having trouble picking out logic error

Tags: java, recursion, logic

I am just practicing my binary search with an int array and can not quite figure out why my logic is off. I have traced my code and it is all adding up to me. The code compiles fine however; I'm missing some logic. could I have an extra set of eyes trace my small segment?

I do not think I need that return 0; but I can not get my code to compile without having a return outside my else.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] data = new int[]{5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60};
        int first = 0;
        int last = data.length;
        int target = 55;
        System.out.print(BinarySearch(data,first,last,target));
    }
    public static int BinarySearch(int[] data, int first, int last,int target)
    {
        if(first > last)
            return -1;
        else{
            int middle = (first+last)/2;
            if(target == data[middle])
                return data[middle];
            else if(target < data[middle])
                BinarySearch(data,first,middle-1,target);
            else
                BinarySearch(data,middle+1,last,target);
        }
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ignoring the result of your recursive calls.

Return the result of the recursive calls.

```
return BinarySearch(data,first,middle-1,target);
```

and

```
return BinarySearch(data,middle+1,last,target);
```

Then you can remove the `return 0;` at the end; it's now unreachable code.

Also, your `BinarySearch` method will be more useful if it returns the index of where it found `target`, e.g. `return middle;` instead of `return data[middle]`.

To avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when searching for a `target` that is too high, assign `data.length - 1` to `last`, not `data.length`.  The initial `first` and `last` must be the minimum possible index and the maximum possible index.

Comment: So it's better to return the index instead of the value?

Comment: Yes.  Returning the value just tells you that it's present in the array.  And if `-1` is what you're looking for, then it tells you nothing.  The purpose of binary search is to find where the target is, not just if it's present.

Comment: One more quick question. how would I check to see if (target not in array)

Comment: You already are checking; it it's not in the array, you return `-1` (an invalid array index).

Comment: Thats what I  thought but it keeps giving me array index out of bounds error.

Comment: I've updated my answer; `last` needs to be `data.length - 1`.